# ¿Para que se usa stat en el código?

Tags: c

Mi profesor me mandó comprender el funcionamiento de una función. La idea general la entiendo, pero hay una parte del código que no entiendo por que la usa. La línea del código la cual no entiendo su finalidad es la siguiente:

```
if (!stat(buf, &statbuf)){
```

El código de la función entera es el siguiente:

```
int borrarContenidoDirectorio (char *nom){
    DIR *directorio = opendir(nom);
    size_t path_lon = strlen(nom);
    int r = -1;
    if (directorio){
        struct dirent *direntd;
    r = 0;
    while (!r && (direntd =readdir(directorio))){
        int r2 = -1;
        char *buf;
        size_t lon;
        if (!strcmp(direntd ->d_name, ".") || !strcmp(direntd -> d_name, ".."))
            continue;
        lon = path_lon + strlen(direntd -> d_name) + 20;
        buf = malloc(lon);
        if (buf){
            struct stat statbuf;
            int aux;
            snprintf(buf, lon, "%s/%s", nom, direntd -> d_name);
            aux = EsDirectorio(buf);
            if (!stat(buf, &statbuf)){
                if (EsDirectorio(buf))
                    r2 = borrarContenidoDirectorio(buf);
                else 
                    r2 = unlink(buf); //borra nombre S.F    
                if (aux == -1){ //Comprobar si es un directorio
                    perror(buf);
                    break;
                }
            }
            free(buf);
        }
        r = r2;
    }
    closedir(directorio);
}   
if (!r)
  r= rmdir (nom);    
return r;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La funcion `stat` retorna informacion sobre un archivo o directorio a traves de un argumento de salida.

Esta declarada de la siguiente forma:

```
int stat(const char *restrict path, struct stat *restrict buf);
```

Stat retorna `-1` si ocurre algun error para obtener la informacion sobre el archivo o directorio del que estas intentando obtener informacion.

Un ejemplo sencillo del uso de `stat` para comprobar si un directorio existe, es un archivo o un directorio:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  if (argc < 2)
    return fprintf(stderr, "Uso: %s <archivo/dir1> [<archivo/dirN>]\n", *argv);

  --argc, ++argv;
  while (argc) {
    struct stat st;
    if (-1 == stat(*argv, &st))
      fprintf(stderr, "No se pudo abrir el archivo o directorio '%s'.\n", *argv);
    else if (S_ISDIR(st.st_mode))
      printf("La direccion '%s' es un directorio.\n", *argv);
    else
      printf("'%s' es un archivo :).\n", *argv);

    --argc, ++argv;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Para utilizarse debe incluirse el archivo `<sys/stat.h>` si tu compilador/plataforma lo soporta:

```
#include <sys/stat.h>
```

La estructura `stat` puede usar para obtener la longitud del archivo en bytes utilizando el campo `st_size` de la estructura, asi como el modo con el campo `st_mode` y las macros que se definen en `sys/stat.h`.

> En el caso de tu funcion, stat obtiene informacion sobre un subdirectorio o direccion a un archivo en la variable `buf` y luego procede si retorna cero.

Comment: ¿Necesito liberar memoria usada en la variable st??